# $f'(x)=0$ implies $f$ constant, although finite or countable exceptions

Tags: calculus

I am reading a text and I do not know why this follows:

> I $f$ is a continuous function and $f'(x)=0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ except for a finite set $E$ or a countable set $E$, then $f$ must be constant.

Does anybody know an example for such an function?

Comment: your function is not continuous.

Comment: you're right. but which function is continuous and in one point different then in others?

Comment: derivative is undefined at $x=2.$

Comment: @monoid in point different then others (so constant on the rest) excludes continuity. No such function exist.

Comment: @drhab how can I picture to myself such a function in the above statement?

Comment: I am afraid there is only one way for that: the function must be constant. I cannot answer next questions on this. Time lacks, sorry.

Comment: If you want to see an example of a continous function with $f'(x)=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb R\backslash E$, where $E$ is a countable or finite set, then it is better to explicitely ask for it in your question.

Comment: Well it is known that a derivative has IVP, so if one claims there is a countable number of points where $f'(x) \neq 0$ then one can draw a contradiction...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function
This functions is continuous and f'(x) = 0 almost everywhere, and the function is not constant.

Comment: @zairhenrique I do know the Cantor-Function, but this is not a constant function.

Comment: Yes, I posted the link to show a counter-example.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is a common one in that the formulation of the result can be at odds with everyday usage of the language.

The **only** examples of such $f$ are in fact constant functions, which have $f'(x)= 0$ for all $x$.

What does

> [...] $f'(x)=0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ except for a finite set $E$ or a countable set $E$, [...]

mean to say precisely?

It means to say that there is a set $E$ that is finite or countable such that $f'(x)= 0$ for all $x \notin E$.

Note that:

- $E$ can be empty.
- It is not uncommon that the author does not insist that $f'(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in E$.

Informally, the result says if for continous $f$ you know $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$ except *possibly* some few exceptions, then you can conclude that $f$ is constant (and after that you'd know in fact $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$).

In particular, this result tells you that there cannot be any interesting examples: by the very result every example has to be constant!